# How do I set the default ftp root folder for an Ubuntu user connecting to VSFTPD?

Tags: ftp, root, user-default

How do I set/change the default ftp root folder for a specific user?  I want to be able to create a developer account that homes to different sites on a development box depending on what is currently being worked on.

EDIT:  The server is running Ubuntu and vsftpd.

Comment: What FTP software are you use? What authentication methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specify the `user_config_dir` in `vsftpd.conf`, you can set any config option on a per-user basis.

From `man vsftpd.conf`:

> This powerful option allows the override of any config option specified in the manual page, on a per-user basis. Usage is simple, and is best illustrated with an example. If you set user_config_dir to be /etc/vsftpd_user_conf and then log on as the user "chris", then vsftpd will apply the settings in the file /etc/vsftpd_user_conf/chris for the duration of the session.

So, setting `local_root` in this way to the desired directory changes the FTP root for just that user.

Answer (score 0):

you can try -s option to run a text file containing FTP commands. In that command file you can easily lcd to different dirs.
Please note this option is not available on all the Unix servers.
Can elaborate on your requirement like which OS Win Or *nix etc ??.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a directory like `OtherDisk` in `~/`, and do this line to create a link, `ln -s / /home/<yourname>/OtherDisk/`, and then you gain the access right to `/`

Comment: THank you, but I don't think that this is what the OP is looking for.